# How to solve? Flutter (6629): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Can anyone solve this problem?

#### this is Error

```
E/flutter (6629): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' was called on null.
E/flutter (6629): Receiver: null
```

E/flutter ( 6629): Tried calling: createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: "nehalt88@gmail.com", password: "123456")
E/flutter ( 6629): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
E/flutter ( 6629): #1      RegistrationScreen.registerNewUser (package:rider_app/AllScreens/registrationScreen.dart:189:10)
E/flutter ( 6629): #2      RegistrationScreen.build. (package:rider_app/AllScreens/registrationScreen.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 6629): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
E/flutter ( 6629): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
E/flutter ( 6629): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
E/flutter ( 6629): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter ( 6629): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
E/flutter ( 6629): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
E/flutter ( 6629): #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:444:20)
E/flutter ( 6629): #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
E/flutter ( 6629): #11     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
E/flutter ( 6629): #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter ( 6629): #13     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter ( 6629): #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter ( 6629): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter ( 6629): #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
E/flutter ( 6629): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 6629): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter ( 6629): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:185:10)
E/flutter ( 6629): #20     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
E/flutter ( 6629): #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:98:31)
E/flutter ( 6629):
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6629): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6629): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6629): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6629): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 6629): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the code where you're trying to call this `createUserWithEmailPassword` method? Or, even better, the entire file where you're calling this method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not importing whatever it is that contains the method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. If you have a code snippet, I can point you into a more specific direction.